# Maintain changes in database via generic approach triggers into history table

Tags: sql-server, replication, entity-framework, temporal-tables

Our main system database has temporal tables

These have helped us hugely in working out issues

However. A drawback of this is that an issue with doing a lot of updates at once can lead to a an error about not being able to update the temporal table due to the time being earlier than the period start time for the affected records

I get this error when updating the database through entity framework core

I need a solution where I can get a temporal table like audit but any issues do not ever get back to the system and stop a transaction from happening

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Has anyone tried a trigger based fix?

This is using azure Sql

In a perfect world our replica database would get the changes and then write to a temporal table but I’m assuming that’s not an option as I would assume that the whole structure of the source and replicated database have to be identical
Paul

Comment: It is best to quote the error exactly.

Answer (score 0):

My choice of change tracking features, mostly due to automation and flexibility, in order of preference:

1. [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) - Has some limitations and can be a little buggy (as you've noticed)
2. [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - Requires manual implementation and maintenance
3. [CDC (Change Data Capture)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) - Has even more limitations than Temporal Tables
4. [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) - Doesn't keep a full history or the timestamp of when the change occurred
5. [Ledger Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/ledger/ledger-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) - Only available in latest Microsoft SQL products. I have no experience with.

> I need a solution where I can get a temporal table like audit but any issues do not ever get back to the system and stop a transaction from happening

Next up would be Triggers and would give you the full control of handling errors however you want. It just also requires the most manual work and maintenance unfortunately. But it is one of the most traditional go-tos for tracking changes.

> In a perfect world our replica database would get the changes and then write to a temporal table but I’m assuming that’s not an option as I would assume that the whole structure of the source and replicated database have to be identical

This would depend on what technology you're using to replicate the data between instances. Feel free to elaborate on that.